# TLS two way mutual authentication not working as client didn't send its certificate

Tags: c++, openssl, tls1.2

I am trying to setup two way TLS mutual authentication using below code but it seems client is not sending its own certificate due to which server is rejecting the connection.

```
SSL_METHOD *meth = SSLv23_client_method();

m_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);
if (m_ctx == NULL)
{
    m_sLastError = GetSSLErrors().c_str();
}
else
{
    long options = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3;
    options |= SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1;
    SSL_CTX_set_options(m_ctx, options);
    if (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(m_ctx, "DEFAULT:!EXP:!SSLv2:!DES:!IDEA:!SEED:!3DES:!RC4:!CAMELLIA") != 1)
    {
        m_sLastError = GetSSLErrors().c_str();
        cout << "SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list failed, error";
    }

    try
    {
        //Populate certificate file paths from VMRegistry
        string vmproCertsPath = "/var/tmp";
        string m_serverCertFile;
        string m_rootCACertFile;
        string m_serverCertKeyFile;
        m_serverCertFile.Format("%s/%s", vmproCertsPath.c_str(), "client.pem");
        m_rootCACertFile.Format("%s/%s", vmproCertsPath.c_str(), "ca.pem");
        m_serverCertKeyFile.Format("%s/%s", vmproCertsPath.c_str(), "key.pem");

        int ret = 0;

        // Read server certificate, intermediate certificates and store in SSL context
        // Here server certificate is a mandatory certificate for SSL handshake
        // Intermediate certificates are for additional security.
        ret = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(m_ctx, "/cert.pem");
        if (ret != 1)
        {
            string sErr(GetSSLErrors().c_str());
            cout << "SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file error" << sErr;
            return false;
        }
        cout << "SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file success ret" << ret;

        // Read private key from certificate file
        // We store server certificate & corresponding private key
        // in same file, which of of PEM format.
        ret = SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(m_ctx, "/key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
        if (ret != 1)
        {
            string sErr(GetSSLErrors().c_str());
            cout << "SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file error" << sErr;
            return false;
        }
        cout << "SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file success ret" << ret;

        // Validate if certificate & private key match.
        ret = SSL_CTX_check_private_key(m_ctx);
        if (ret != 1)
        {
            string sErr(GetSSLErrors().c_str());
            cout << "Private key does not match the certificate public key";
            return false;
        }
        cout << "SSL_CTX_check_private_key success ret" << ret;

        // Read CA certificate
        // Even if we are unable to read CA certificate SSL context should get populated
        // Lets not return flase on failure
        ret = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(m_ctx, "/ca.pem", NULL);
        if (ret != 1)
        {
            string sErr(GetSSLErrors().c_str());
            cout << sErr;
        }
        cout << "SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations success ret" << ret;

        //Won't handle incomplete read/write due to renegotiation
        //SSL_CTX_set_mode(m_ctx, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

        //Specify that we need to verify the server certificate
        SSL_CTX_set_verify(m_ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, NULL);

        SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(m_ctx, 1);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Exception occured";
    }
}
```

Also observed that when server reject the connection I am not getting any error and still the socket is in connected state.
Any thoughts what incorrect with above code.

Comment: Since it's being rejected early then it's happening before it gets to sending the client certificate.  Try removing the SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list call to see if you are restricting the chipper list to much for the server.

Comment: SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT is ignored for client setups.  It's for server setups only so you can remove that option.

Comment: SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth seems very shallow, try removing that as well.